Conditions for a set of coordinates to qualify as action-angle coordinates
TL;DR: Action-angle coordinates have a specific definition, but is there a condition that a set of coordinates must satisfy in order to be called action-angle? Is any coordinate system where the coordinates evolve linearly with time and the momenta are constant an action-angle coordinate system?
So in general, when we have a Hamiltonian system which is completely separable (i.e. has $n$ independent integrals in involution), we can solve the time independent Hamilton-Jacobi equation
$$H(q_i, \partial S_{0} / \partial q_i) = \alpha_1$$
for a function $S_0(q_i, \alpha_i)$ of the coordinates and $n$ constants $\alpha_i$ (one of which can be taken as the energy). We then define the action variables
$$J_i = \oint p_i\, dq_i$$
as integrals over a cycle of the motion, express the constants $\alpha_i$ in terms of the $J_i$ and finally get our generating function $S_0(q_i, J_i)$, from which the angle variables can be found as $\theta_i = \partial S_0 / \partial J_i$. We then find that the angle variables evolve linearly in time, with the frequencies given by $\omega_i = \partial H / \partial J_i$ (possibly with some factors of $2\pi$ somewhere).
But why is the definition of the $J_i$ necessary? If from the generating function $S_0(q_i, \alpha_i)$ we take the $\alpha_i$ as momenta and define the coordinates $\beta_i = \partial S_0 / \partial \alpha_i$, then the $\alpha_i$ are constant and the $\beta_i$ evolve linearly in time. In particular, if $\alpha_1$ is the energy then $\beta_1$ has unit speed and all the other "angles" are constant.
Does this coordinate system also qualify as action-angle coordinates? Is there some property that $(\theta, J)$ has that $(\beta, \alpha)$ doesn't?

Integrable bound motion can be understood as a set of $n$ separable, generally nonlinear oscillations. Since each oscillation looks like motion on a circle $S^1$ in phase space, the total motion is on the $n$-dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^n = S^1\times ... \times S^1$. The torus can be found as the hypersurface of constant integrals of motion $\alpha_j = const.$ and from this set of constraints we can express $p_i(\alpha_j,q^k)$ for the motion. To define an action, we choose a set of curves $\gamma_A, A=1,...n$ that are single-wound independent loops over such tori and compute
$$ J_A = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \oint_{\gamma_A} \sum_i p_i dq^i $$
Each loop $\gamma_A$ corresponds to an independent oscillation or cycle of motion. When the motion is separable in some special set of coordinates $Q^i$, it is natural to make the cycles $\gamma_A$ correspond to cycles in each such $Q^i$ (this is the assumption behing your original $J_i$ definition). The canonically conjugate angle to action $J_A$ can be understood as a sort of a phase of this cycle/oscillation and it is $2\pi$-periodic. The $2\pi$ period corresponds to finishing a cycle homotopic to $\gamma_A$.
When using any other constant of motion than an action as a canonical momentum, the canonically conjugate variable will have different properties. The biggest issue that one encounters is that the conjugate variable is generally not $2\pi$-periodic. In fact, its period is generally a non-trivial function of phase space. So if you use $\beta_i, \alpha_i$ as suggested in your post, the $\beta_i$ will evolve linearly over time, but its value carries no indication whether you have finished a full cycle of motion. If you try to rescale $\beta_i$ by its period to get a unique phase-type variable, you have to also rescale the canonically conjugate momentum $\alpha_i$. It turns out that when you do this, you implicitly have to carry out the same computations as those leading to action-angle coordinates, and as a result you get... action-angle coordinates.
